# Why route flushing on Mac fails with "got only -1 for rlen"?

Tags: macos, routing

Flushing routes on MacOSX 10.11.6:

```
route -n flush -inet
```

This often only removes a few routes and fails with:

```
route: write to routing socket: No such process
got only -1 for rlen
```

Why so and how can it be fixed?